# ftp: special characters in password

Tags: linux, ftp, special-characters

I need to execute this command

```
wget -r ftp://$USER:$PASSWORD@$SITE/
```

*But* first since there were some special characters (such as '!?') within the PASSWORD I had some problems that I solved by escaping them with '\'..

Now I am facing the problem that special character don't work with the ftp command...([here](http://www.wapopia.com/blog/2010/08/05/wget-bad-port-number-error/))

At the moment I get this:

```
Bad port number
```

This is because also some numbers are present within the PASSWORD, I tried to single-quote, but without success..

How can I solve, if I would not change the password?

On terminal, on Debian.

Comment: Use the --ftp-user and --ftp-password parameters instead of encoding it into the URL.

Comment: @Joe It worked, thanks. If you wanna make an answer I will choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--ftp-user` and `--ftp-password` parameters instead of encoding it into the URL

Comment: I'd love an example on how to do this, since the ftp man page doesn't have an `ftp-user` flag.

Comment: That's because the question (and answer) are about `wget`